# Add pause function to soundjs

Tags: javascript, soundjs

I have tried using:

1. `createjs.Sound.pause;`
2. `mySound.stop();`

Nothing works. Right now it have a stop button but if the stop button is pressed then the sound would not be played again.

This is the soundjs that im using.  [soundjs](http://createjs.com/tutorials/SoundJS%20and%20PreloadJS/internalPreloading.html)

My code is exactly the same with the source code of it. Thanks for any help!

I end up doing it like this Based on Stephen Lightcap answer:

Javascript inside the head tag:

```
    function load() {
        // Update the UI
        document.getElementById("display").innerText = ".";


        // Load the sound
        createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
        createjs.Sound.registerSound({id:"mySound", src:"../../test.mp3"});
    }

    function handleFileLoad(event) {
        // Update the UI
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = ".";
        document.getElementById("stopBtn").disabled = "";

        // Play the loaded sound
        createjs.Sound.play(event.src,{loop:2});

    }
    var instance = createjs.Sound.play(event.src);
</script>
```

Button inside the body tag:

`<input id="pausBtn" type="button" value="Pause" onclick="pause()"/>`

Javascript for the button onclick. Placed below the button. :

```
<script>
function pause(){
instance.pause();
}
</script>
```

But I got an error saying :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
    at pause (phkk.html:560)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (phkk.html:177)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in an var and then use the function `pause()`

```
var instance = createjs.Sound.play(event.src);
```

Have button that calls a method that will store the pause

```
<input id="pausBtn" type="button" value="Pause" onclick="pause()"/>
```

The JS function:

```
function pause(){
    instance.pause();
}
```

**EDIT**

I went over the docs and it appears it doesn't function like that any more, so you're going to have to use the [paused property](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/AbstractSoundInstance.html#property_paused)

Here's a rough outline on how it works for me:

```
<script>

    var instance; 

    function load() {
        // Update the UI
        document.getElementById("display").innerText = ".";


        // Load the sound
        createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
        createjs.Sound.registerSound({id:"mySound", src:"../../test.mp3"});
    }

   function handleFileLoad(event) {
       // Update the UI
       document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = ".";
       document.getElementById("stopBtn").disabled = "";

       // Play the loaded sound
       instance = createjs.Sound.play(event.src,{loop:2});

   }

   function pause(){
       instance.paused ? instance.paused = false : instance.paused = true;
   }



</script>
```

The HTML buttons:

```
<body>
<input id="loadBtn" type="button" value="Begin Loading" onclick="load()"/>
<input id="stopBtn" type="button" value="Stop Playing" onclick="createjs.Sound.stop();" disabled="disabled" />
    <input id="pauseBtn" type="button" value="Pause" onclick="pause()"/>
<label id="display">Waiting for User Input. Click "Begin Loading".</label>
```

Comment: I know this is simple but I would like to know where should I put the `var instance = createjs.Sound.play(event.src);` ? And thanks for the help. :D

Comment: I have edited my post and testing your code. I hope you don't mind to check and correct the mistake I did. Thanks! @Stephen Lightcap

Comment: @C.topo check out the edit, it's working on my machine as is, just replace the file with your audio file

Comment: I have followed and even copy paste all your code. But the pause button did nothing. Nothing error being shown also, weird. Btw I really appreciate your help and Thanks again! I'll try to fix this and let you know the result later. :D @Stephen Lightcap

Comment: Is there a way I can send you the code that Im working on? I mean the html file of it. Maybe in that way you can try to run it on your pc. Because I did try it on mozilla and chrome and the pause are still not working. @Stephen Lightcap

Comment: Here the link to view it @Stephen Lightcap. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7_v0AE5KCO7SFc0d1B4dnRYNkU

Comment: @C.topo Yeah it wasn't working until I used the 0.6.2 version over 0.5.2 - `<script src="http://code.createjs.com/soundjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>` made it work

Comment: Thanks! It finally work. Sorry a bit busy and dont have time to online until now. You a lifesaver. :D  @Stephen Lightcap